# How to optimize a MySQL joining to itself?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, query-performance

I need to optimize a MySQL (5.7.12) query. I've been reading the docs about optimization in MySQL docs but It's been hard for me to comprehend it. I have two tables:

vehicles

```sql
CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`metadata` json DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`license_plate` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`vehicle_type` varchar(205) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`brand` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`model` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`color` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`fuel_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`agency_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`code` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`vehicle_line` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`initial_odometer` double DEFAULT NULL,
`reference` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`fuel_chip` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`engine_displacement` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`driver_data` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `vehicles_code_unique` (`code`),
KEY `vehicles_agency_id_foreign` (`agency_id`),
CONSTRAINT `vehicles_agency_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`agency_id`) REFERENCES `agencies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1561 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

positions

```sql
CREATE TABLE `positions` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`vehicle_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`latitude` double NOT NULL,
`longitude` double NOT NULL,
`speed` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`alarm` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`altitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
`direction` double DEFAULT NULL,
`metadata` json DEFAULT NULL,
`time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`event_type` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `positions_vehicle_id_time_deleted_at_index` (`vehicle_id`,`time`,`deleted_at`),
KEY `positions_time_index` (`time`),
KEY `speed` (`speed`),
CONSTRAINT `positions_vehicle_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicles` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=105581942 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

As you can see, I have 1561 records on `vehicles` and 105581942 on `positions`. I need to get the vehicles with its latest position which speed is over 5, in the same row. That's determined by the `positions.time` field, not by `created_at` or `id`. I have the next SQL optimized, it gets the latest position per vehicle:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM positions a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(time) mxdate
FROM positions
GROUP BY vehicle_id
) b
ON a.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id
AND a.time = b.mxdate;
```

[image: EXPLAIN output for quick query]

MySQL responds very quickly with it, but if I add `speed` to the subquery, "It never ends":

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM positions a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(time) mxdate
FROM positions
where speed > 5
GROUP BY vehicle_id
) b
ON a.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id
AND a.time = b.mxdate;
```

[image: EXPLAIN output for slow query]

I added this at the end: `AND a.speed > 5` but my boss told me that it's better to use it in the subquery.

In the end, I need query shown above but I think optimizing the innermost query is enough.

```sql
select v.*,
       lastlocations.speed,
       lastlocations.latitude,
       lastlocations.longitude,
       lastlocations.time,
       lastlocations.event_type
from vehicles v,
     (
         SELECT a.*
         FROM positions a
                  INNER JOIN
              (
                  SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(time) mxdate
                  FROM positions
                  GROUP BY vehicle_id
              ) b ON a.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id
                  AND a.time = b.mxdate
     ) lastlocations
where v.id = lastlocations.vehicle_id;
```

**UPDATE**:
After creating an index like this: `positions_speed_vehicle_id_time_index (speed, vehicle_id, time)`, the `EXPLAIN` output looks better:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've been oriented to find a way.

After creating an index like this: `positions_speed_vehicle_id_time_index (speed, vehicle_id, time)`, the `EXPLAIN` output looks better:
[image]

Here it is the explanation (I received in an image):
[image]

I would like a more optimized query, but that's what I get right now.

Answer (score 2):

- Shrink the table size to help with performance.
- `DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes; `FLOAT` takes 4.  `FLOAT` provides 1.7 meter resolution, sufficient for vehicles.
- Do you use `created_at` and `updated_at`?
- Do you fill in the address for every entry?  Seems like a waste of time (and space).
- Consider storing only actions where moving > 5.  (Is that km/hr?)
- Consider a third table for the 'current' location; this gets updated on every input record.  It would be quite small (1561 rows).
- Your 105M `positions` is probably growing quite rapidly.  There will be other performance issues in the near future, other than this one `SELECT`.
- What other queries will soon need optimizing?
- Do you use `positions.id` for anything?  Whether or not you do, I may have further optimizations.

Comment: I use `time` to get more recent positions. If I locally change `double` by `float`, I'm getting the same output executing `explain expanded`.

Comment: * I don't fill in the address for every row. It's just searched on Google when needed.
* We have to store actions < 5 km/hr (kph) because we need to know when the vehicles were stopped.
* We have the current locations on Redis but we have to know what was the last position before the vehicle stops.